# How to Customize Django Admin Filter

Tags: django

Using django **1.7.7** admin page, I want to list the data in a table where I can sort and filter.
That's exactly what the picture on the documentation shows:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/
under the list_filter section.
I tried that and got an error:
The value of 'list_display[0]' refers to 'book_type', which is not a callable.
Then, I tried this:

```
# model.py:
class Interp():
    """ specifies the interpretation model """
    BOOK_TYPES = ['drama', 'scietific']
    BOOK_TYPES = tuple(zip(BOOK_TYPES, BOOK_TYPES))
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    book_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=BOOK_TYPES,
                                   default='not specified')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.book_type

# admin.py:
class bookTypeFilter(SimpleListFilter):                                           
      title = 'book type'                                                           
      parameter_name = 'book_type'                                                  

      def lookups(self, request, model_admin):                                        
          types = set([t.book_type for t in model_admin.model.objects.all()])       
          return zip(types, types)                                                    

      def queryset(self, request, queryset):                                          
          if self.value():                                                            
              return queryset.filter(book_type__id__exact=self.value())             
          else:                                                                       
              return queryset                                                         


  class AdminInterpStore(admin.ModelAdmin):                                           
      """ admin page setting """                                                      
      search_fields = ('comment', 'book_type')                                          
      list_display = ('book_type',)                                                 
      list_filter = (bookTypeFilter, )
```

this shows a sidebar and lists the values but as soon as I click any of them, I get an error:

```
FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'id' for CharField or join on the field not permitted
```

- How can I make a filter, preferably a table view as well?
- Is the a complete sample for django1.7.7 that I can look at for filtering admin page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must replace

```
return queryset.filter(book_type__id__exact=self.value())
```

by

```
return queryset.filter(book_type=self.value())
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups for more information.

Also, in the `lookups` method, using:

```
types = model_admin.model.objects.distinct('book_type').values_list('book_type', flat=True)
```

would be much more efficient as you would not retrieve the whole data from the database to then filter it.

**Edit:**
I realized that the `book_type` field is a [choice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices) field.

First, the value passed to the `choices` argument must be

> An iterable (e.g., a list or tuple) consisting itself of iterables of exactly two items (e.g. [(A, B), (A, B) ...] A being the value stored in the database, B a human readable value)

So passing a list of strings will fail.

Second, the Django admin's default behaviour for such fields is exactly what you are trying to achieve so setting `list_filter = ('book_type', )` in `AdminInterpStore`  is enough.

Comment: Thanks. You suggestion worked. I also updated the code. I did actually convert my choices to a tuple of paired tuples using the zip command and yet setting list_filter=('book_type',) fails. Since overriding SimpleListFilter requires a lot of boiler plate code, does anyone know why the default behaviour with a tuple string does not work?

Comment: got it. I was mistakenly using two admin.site.register(...) for two tables with the same handler. I must have used separate handlers.